# HHVM Crashes after 12 requests (jit_warmup_requests)

Tags: hhvm

For some reason my HHVM setup crashes after the initial 12 requests  (jit_warmup_requests). I can't see any useful information as to why this is in the logs. If I disable JIT it works fine and if I increase the "jit_warmup_requests" to 20 for example I only get 7 successful requests.

HHVM Version 3.5.0

NGINX Version 1.6.2

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Here is my server.ini

```
; php options

pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

; hhvm specific 
hhvm.server.port = 9001
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
hhvm.server.apc.enable_apc = true
hhvm.server.apc.table_type = concurrent
hhvm.server.apc.expire_on_sets = true
hhvm.server.apc.purge_frequency = 4096

hhvm.jit = true

hhvm.eval.jit = true
hhvm.eval.jit_warmup_requests = 20

hhvm.log.level = Error
hhvm.log.no_silencer = true
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.use_syslog = false
hhvm.log.injected_stack_trace = true
hhvm.log.native_stack_trace = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log

hhvm.error_handling.call_user_handler_on_fatals = true
hhvm.error_handling.max_loop_count = 0
hhvm.error_handling.no_infinite_recursion_detection = false
hhvm.error_handling.throw_bad_type_exceptions = false
hhvm.error_handling.throw_too_many_arguments = false
hhvm.error_handling.warn_too_many_arguments = false
hhvm.error_handling.throw_missing_arguments = false
hhvm.error_handling.throw_invalid_arguments = false
hhvm.error_handling.enable_hip_hop_errors = true
hhvm.error_handling.notice_frequency = 1
hhvm.error_handling.warning_frequency = 1
hhvm.error_handling.assert_active = false
hhvm.error_handling.assert_warning = false

hhvm.debug.full_backtrace = true
hhvm.debug.server_stack_trace = true
hhvm.debug.server_error_message = true
hhvm.debug.translate_source = true
hhvm.debug.record_input = false
hhvm.debug.clear_input_on_success = true
hhvm.debug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp
hhvm.debug.core_dump_email = email address
hhvm.debug.core_dump_report = true
hhvm.debug.core_dump_report_directory = /tmp
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Small advice: if you get no helpful answers here about your problem, I recommend opening an issue on HHVM's GitHub page. It would get much higher visibility there. But +1, good question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Radu, I'll pop this question up on their GitHub page :)